# Count based on hash map class value

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a hash map of type:

```
 val studentById: <Int, StudentDetails>
```

StudentDetails has columns such as: ActiveCourse and CourseID.
I would like to count number of students that have taken each course.
So for every courseID that is in all StudentDetails, group and count number of students linked to it where ActiveCourse is true.
Is it possible to do something like:

```
   studentById.mapValues{
      it.values.groupBy{ courseId}.countEach student id where activeCourse is true.
    }
```

The end result should be something like:

```
coursesCountStudents <Int (courseId), Int (number of active students)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply operations to groups created when using the groupingBy operation.
It seems like [Grouping﻿](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-grouping.html) will be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the `StudentDetails` contains a list of courses.

```kotlin
fun countCourses(students: Map<Int, StudentDetails>): Map<Int, Int>
{
    val coursesCountStudents = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
    students.forEach { (studentId, details) ->
        // I'm using a stream here so we only iterate over the array once during the filtering and processing steps
        details.courses.stream()
            .filter { it.ActiveCourse }
            .forEach {
                coursesCountStudents[it.courseId] = coursesCountStudents[it.courseId]?.inc() ?: 1
            }
        }
    }
    return coursesCountStudents
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't contain a list of courses though. It's only one course that is either active or not. So there is a courseID UUID field, and courseActive Boolean field.
Every student id is associated with one course in studentDetails. But this courseID can be repeated with other studentIds, so I need to count how many students are active in each course.

Comment: That's fine, instead of iterating over a courses property you can just do `if (details.courseActive) coursesCountStudents[details.courseID] = coursesCountStudents[details.courseID]?.inc() ?: 1`